# JQuery onclick() последовательное изменение css

Tags: html, jquery, css

Нужно чтобы, после нажатия на иконку ширина некого div.content становилась 1000px, после повторного нажатия на иконку, размер div-а должен становиться прежним.
Свой способ засунуть в onlick() функцию animate() не устраивает, так как ограничивается количеством вложений функций одна в одну, нужно более  практичный код.[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Comment: То, что "нужно" - это хорошо. А может покажите то, что уже сами пробовали делать? В конце концов, вы же не на фрилансе...

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, как раз то что искал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавлять класс с шириной в 1000px пример http://jsfiddle.net/zvqsrt2o/1/